# Ayuda básica en graficas en R

Tags: r

estoy aprendiendo R, ¿Cómo puedo graficar dos variables pero que debo agruparlas primero?

Es decir tengo el número de horas de sueño de personas y por otro lado si a estas personas se les comunico si tienen la presión alta.

Entonces necesito  por ejemplo al grupo de personas que duermen 8 horas hay 10 que tienen presión alta y 10 que no, es decir el 50% no lo tiene, entonces este 50% es el que quiero graficar[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí] en excel este es el resultado[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Saludos Victoria, bienvenida a SOes. Coloca el código por favor :D

Comment: Hola Fredy, justamente no tengo el código porque estoy recien aprendiendo (editaron el título de mi pregunta no se por que) no es un problema si no que necesito saber como graficar esto, lo último que ingrese fue:

Comment: nueva2%>%
+ group_by(bphigh4,sleptim1)%>%
+ summarise(count=n())
Source: local data frame [45 x 3]
Groups: bphigh4 [?]

Comment: Desconozco dicho lenguaje, sin embargo aquí te alcanzo unos enlaces para que puedas aprender :D http://www.tutorialspoint.com/r/ - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt238409.aspx - https://www.codeschool.com/courses/try-r - y la documentación oficial: https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html :D

Answer (score 0):

Antes que nada, Bienvenida a SO. Te recomiendo que les des una mirada a [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) para que sea más fácil poder responder. Voy a intentar pasar en limpio tu pregunta, la primera dificultad con la que me encuentro, es que no tengo una idea de como son los datos, no adjuntas una muestra aunque sea mínima ni indicas un enlace de dónde obtenerlos, sin estos datos muchas veces resulta imposible hacer un análisis, por ejemplo, apriori no sé si los datos que mencionas son numéricos, cadenas etc. Por suerte **Google** ayuda en estos casos y entiendo que estás trabajando sobre el informe "BRFSS" de la **[CDC](https://www.cdc.gov)**, voy a asumir que estamos trabajando sobre el mismo. El otro problema que tienes tu pregunta es que no me queda claro exactamente cual es el requerimiento: ¿necesitás filtrar datos? ¿necesitás graficarlos?

Voy a tratar de responder de todas formas:

Tu primer requerimiento, es que el data.frame original es demasiado grande y solo necesitas dos variables o columnas del mismo, para hacer esto:

```
# Armo un data.farme con las 2 columnas que me interesan
df <- brfss2013[, c("bphigh4","sleptim1")]
```

La pregunta no es consistente con tu comentario posterior, vamos primero con la pregunta, dices:

> necesito por ejemplo al grupo de personas que duermen 8 horas hay 10
>   que tienen presión alta y 10 que no, es decir el 50% no lo tiene,
>   entonces este 50% es el que quiero

Esto se logra filtrando los datos de la siguiente forma:

```
# me quedo solo con los que durmieron 8 o más horas y NO han tenido presión alta (quito los valores Na para no ensuciar)
newdf <- df[ df$bphigh4 == "No" & df$sleptim1 >= 8 & !is.na(df$bphigh4) & !is.na(df$sleptim1),  ]
```

Por otro lado, en tus comentarios das a entender que lo que buscas es agrupar por `bphigh4` y `df$sleptim1` y obtener la cantidad de casos de cada uno, esto lo podrías hacer así:

```
newdf<-aggregate(rep(1, nrow(df)) ~ bphigh4 + sleptim1, data = df, FUN=length)
colnames(newdf)[3] <- "cantidad"
```

Espero te sirva